# xslt - extract leaf nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract only the leaf nodes from an XML document (i.e., only elements that have no children). Has anyone written an xslt to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT="*[not(*)]"
```

Should give you anything without a child.

Comment: This worked for me. Though I had to use 'SELECT="//*[not(*)]"'. I'm a xslt newbie and don't why the '//' part is necessary, but I'm still learning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The "//" is so that it will find the condition "*[not(*)]" anywhere in the xml structure.

Answer (score 2):

Using axes in XPath:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//you-node-spec[not(child::*)]" />
```